# filter array items with respect to another array in angular controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

I have an list as,

```
$scope.list1= [{"name":"name1","id":1},{"name":"name2","id":2},{"name":"name3","id":3},{"name":"name4","id":4}];
```

I want to filter this list with respect to another list as,

```
$scope.list2=[1,3];
```

Here I want filter list1 so that only those objects items are left ehich are in list2. i.e

after filter

```
$scope.list1= [{"name":"name1","id":1},{"name":"name3","id":3}];
```

I can do this by using the splice function . But I want to ask that whether this can be done using the $filter without using a loop.

Comment: How about underscore.js? I like it a lot for doing those kind of tasks without having loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do that with the open source project jinqJs http://www.jinqJs.com

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/zky1hoj8/1/)

```
var list1= [{"name":"name1","id":1},{"name":"name2","id":2},{"name":"name3","id":3},{"name":"name4","id":4}];
var list2= [1,3];

var result = jinqJs().from(list1).where(function(row){
    return (list2.indexOf(row.id) > -1);
}).select();
```

OR

this way

```js
//Use jsJinq.com open source library
var list1= [{"name":"name1","id":1},{"name":"name2","id":2},{"name":"name3","id":3},{"name":"name4","id":4}];
var list2= [1,3];

var result = jinqJs().from(list1).join(list2).on('id').select();

document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.js"></script>
```